# Failing fast by raising an exception with a custom message

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, error-handling, meta-programming

This is a script that utilizes lazy exception throwing. What I do is decorate a function that might throw an exception to throw an exception with a formatted string.

```
from functools import wraps

def on_fail(message):
    def on_fail_dec(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def on_fail_wrapper(*args, **kw):
            ret = None
            success = True
            message_addon = ""
            try:
                ret = func(*args, **kw)
            except Exception as e:
                success = False
                message_addon = str(e)
            # raise Exception if failed
            if not success:
                raise Exception("{0}\nBecause: {1}".format(message, message_addon))

            return ret
        return on_fail_wrapper
    return on_fail_dec

# Usage :

@on_fail("Division Failed")
def divide(a, b):
    return a / b

test_cases = [(1, 2), (20, 5), (3, 0)]

for a,b in test_cases:
    print("Trying to divide {0} from {1}".format(a, b))
    print(divide(a, b))
```

Output:

> ```
> Trying to divide 1 from 2
> 0.5
> Trying to divide 20 from 5
> 4.0
> Trying to divide 3 from 0
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 30, in <module>
>   File "<string>", line 16, in on_fail_wrapper
> Exception: Division Failed
> Because: division by zero
> ```

Comment: I don't understand, what do mean by lazy exception throwing here?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I want to fail fast raising an Exception with a custom message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Instead of handling just `"Division Failed"` you should extend your function to handle any possible error, plus it's better if you pass the exception object along with the `message` to the decorator as well, by doing this you'll know exactly which error you're going to handle because a `except Exception` will handle any `Exception` not just what we actually intended it to.
- Second there's no need to use flag variables here, we can simply return the return value from the try-block and in case of exception we re-raise the exception after it is caught.

**Code:**

```
from functools import wraps


def on_fail(exception, message):
    def on_fail_dec(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def on_fail_wrapper(*args, **kw):
            message_addon = ""
            try:
                # do something before
                ret = func(*args, **kw)
                # do something after
                return ret
            except exception as e:
               message_addon = str(e)
            raise exception("{0}\nBecause: {1}".format(message, message_addon))
        return on_fail_wrapper
    return on_fail_dec


@on_fail(ZeroDivisionError, "Division Failed")
def divide(a, b):
    return a / b

test_cases = [(1, 2), (20, 5), (3, 0)]

for a, b in test_cases:
    print("Trying to divide {0} from {1}".format(a, b))
    print(divide(a, b))
```

Note that in above code I didn't use something simple like:

```
except exception as e:
    raise exception("{0}\nBecause: {1}".format(message, e))
```

That's because Python 3 introduced something called exception chaining, which means if an exception occurs while handling another exception then the previous exception still remains available to us(Read [PEP 3134 - PEP 3134 -- Exception Chaining and Embedded Tracebacks](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/)), but this is not useful here as it will end up raising something like:

```
Trying to divide 3 from 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashwini/py/so.py", line 10, in on_fail_wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ashwini/py/so.py", line 20, in divide
    return a / b
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashwini/py/so.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(divide(a, b))
  File "/home/ashwini/py/so.py", line 13, in on_fail_wrapper
    raise exception("{0}\nBecause: {1}".format(message, e))
ZeroDivisionError: Division Failed
Because: division by zero
```

Comment: How about assigning `exception = type(e)` inside the `except` block, to wrap all exceptions? That would make sense to me if the intent is to describe *what* failed, while the original exception describes *why*?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to initialize the local variables,
and some of them you don't need at all:

- `ret` : instead of saving the return value, you can return directly. If an exception happens you will re-raise, so there will be no other return value except the normal one
- `success` : if nothing is raised, that by itself is success. If something was raise, you'll be out of the `try` block, that's how you'll know it was *not* a success
- `message_addon` : this you *do* need to save in the `except` block, but you don't need to initialize it beforehand

Considering the above, the implementation can be simplified:

```
def on_fail(message):
    def on_fail_dec(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def on_fail_wrapper(*args, **kw):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kw)
            except Exception as e:
                message_addon = str(e)
            raise Exception("{0}\nBecause: {1}".format(message, message_addon))
        return on_fail_wrapper
    return on_fail_dec
```